# Simple addObject to NSMutableArray method gives lldb error

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I'm adding objects to a NSMutableArray stack in my model. Here's the interface:

```
@interface calcModel ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *operandStack;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation calcModel
@synthesize operandStack = _operandStack;

- (NSMutableArray *)operandStack;
{
if (_operandStack == nil) _operandStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
return _operandStack;
}
```

This addobject method works fine:

```
- (void)pushValue:(double)number;
{
[self.operandStack addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:number]];
NSLog(@"Array: %@", self.operandStack);
}
```

but this one crashes the app and just says 'lldb' in the log:

```
- (void)pushOperator:(NSString *)operator;
{
[self.operandStack addObject:operator];
NSLog(@"Array: %@", self.operandStack);
}
```

What's causing this error?

Comment: If you begin Objective-C with the current XCode version, see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html :  @synthesize are no longer needed.

Comment: If it really **just** says "lldb" then you probably set a breakpoint on that line...or you are stopping at an exception breakpoint.

Answer (score 3):

The `NSString` you're adding is probably `nil`. Do this:

```
- (void)pushOperator:(NSString *)operator {
    if (operator) {
        [self.operandStack addObject:operator];
        NSLog(@"Array: %@", self.operandStack);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Oh no, it's nil.");
    }
}
```

If that's the case, figure out why it's `nil` and fix that. Or check it before adding it.

The reason why the first method doesn't crash is, because there is no double value that can't be used to init an `NSNumber`, so it will never be `nil`.

Comment: +1, but note that a semicolon after the method header isn't necessarily a syntax error; some people prefer it in implementation files so that copy & paste is easier between .h and .m files (just triple-click the line and go for it).